# Repeat something after a specific time interval

Tags: java, multithreading, time

I have been going through some of the SO questions about doing something after a specific interval of time (like printing hello world every five seconds).

I saw different ways that we can do it in a java program. my question is how java does this internally.

Once we run a java program, the main function starts executing in a thread. But this thread can be sent to Runnable state anytime(pause the execution). So if I had stated the print statement in the main function, how does java keep track of time now. what if the java program was not resumed for the next five seconds?

One way this could work is if we meant "every 5 seconds in the time period which the java program is **running**" . Is that how the JVM does this?

Assume that I have a single processor.

Comment: It asks the OS to wake it up after 5 seconds.

Comment: is the behaviour guaranteed? will the OS wake it after 5 seconds for sure?

Comment: No, the OS is not guaranteed to wake your process or thread after five seconds for sure. The only OSs that actually give that kind of assurances are hard RealTime OS:es. Not even soft RT will guarantee that you wake exactly after five seconds.

Comment: so the 5 seconds i meant in the program, might not be exactly 5 seconds actual time?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets trace the calls. If we are using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` we can find that it uses `DelayedWorkQueue` internally:

```
super(corePoolSize, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS,
          new DelayedWorkQueue());
```

To await next tasks `DelayedWorkQueue` uses `Condition available = lock.newCondition()`:

```
available.awaitNanos(delay);
```

Ok, lets take a look at `awaitNanos` implementation in `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`:

```
LockSupport.parkNanos(this, nanosTimeout);
```

And the `LockSUpport`:

```
unsafe.park(false, nanos);
```

This is native method which uses operating systems's scheduler to delay thread execution.